# How to get ID in Server Control / C#?

Tags: c#, user-controls

I try to write a simple Server Control to control the Banners in my site.

It should be somethink like:

```
<Banners:mng_bnr ID="Upper_bnr / aside_bnr / bottom_bnr / etc" runat="server" />
```

And then the Control will be something like:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {


 switch(which_banner)
 {
 case which_banner.upper_banner_wide: 
<!-- Ad code -->
 <script type="text/javascript"><!--
JS code
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript"

 </script>
 <!-- *** Ad Code *** --> 
break;

case which_banner.upper_banner_small:
 <!-- Ad code -->
 <script type="text/javascript"><!--
JS code
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript"

 </script>
 <!-- *** Ad Code *** --> 
break;

case which_banner.aside_336_280_top:

 <!-- Ad code -->
 <script type="text/javascript"><!--
JS code
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript"

 </script>
 <!-- *** Ad Code *** -->
```

But, I don't know how to get and handle the ID of each control (there should be around 5-6 controls on each page which every one will have it own ID - which mean different banner)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: <%=Banner.ClientId%> can help you? Actualy I don't understand where do you want to use ids of banners?

Answer (score 1):

This post is overly vague. I *think* what you are asking is how to pass the ID's of your banner control from the parent page into this control.  In that case you would do something like this:

```
 private string _bannerId = string.Empty;
 public string BannerId
 {
      get { return _bannerId; }
      set { _bannerId = value; }
 }
```

Then your switch looks like this:

```
 switch(_bannerId)
 {
     case "banner1":
     break;

     case "banner2":
     break; 
 }
```

Then on your parent page you would do something like this:

```
 <Banners:mng_bnr BannerId="Upper_bnr" runat="server" />
```

If  you want to pass in multiple banner id's I would suggest either using a collection or providing a property for each banner but this really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Hope this helps.

--Edit--

In terms of writing out the necessary code there are  plenty of ways you can do that.   You could, for example, do something like this:

```
switch(_bannerId)
{
 case "banner1":
     scriptLiteral.Text = "<script>...</script>";
 break;

 case "banner2":
     scriptLiteral.Text = "<script>...</script>";
 break; 
}
```

And then on your control you would have

```
<asp:Literal id="scriptLiteral" runat="server" />
```

I would probably use [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx) though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! Just another small question: within the cases I need to put the google advertising

Comment: Can't put the Adsense code within the Literal. It's give error message

Comment: ... I literally can not help you when all you say is 'It gives an error'.  As I said adding a literal control to the page is one way to add a script but I would probably use the RegisterClientScriptBlock class.  Again how you actually achieve adding your script to the page is going to largely depend on what you are trying to do. In most cases I would use the RegisterClientScriptBlock class to add JavaScript to the page at runtime.